Emulating a scroll-wheel on a trackball in Wayland, like I can in X11
I believe the following applies to standard Ubuntu (Gnome) as well as Kubuntu, my preferred environment.  The Logitech T-BC21 Trackman Marble is a USB trackball mouse input.  It has 4 buttons, I call them primary left and right,  secondary left and right.  I want it so that the right secondary button, when pressed, turns the trackball into a scrollwheel.
The solution in X11 is to edit/create a conf file, example in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-trackball.conf I have this content:
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Marble Mouse"
    MatchProduct    "Logitech USB Trackball"
    Driver          "libinput"
    Option          "ScrollMethod" "button"
    Option          "ScrollButton" "9"
Option          "MiddleEmulation" "on"
EndSection

Added bonus, it scrolls horizontally and vertically.
How can I achieve similar under Wayland, specifically Kubuntu 24.10?
